# Windows guest OS Power Plan on vmware: is there any real difference?

Tags: windows, vmware, windows-server

I've been doing some research but cannot find any evidence or KB online about this topic.

Basically as title says: for a Windows Server machine hosted on vmware is there any difference between the power plans on the machine itself?

I've tried to check the resource consumption on both vCenter and the actual machines but could not find any strong evidence about it, is there any official documents on the subject?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking whether the power plan in a Windows VM is important,
then the answer would be that it's of a very minor importance.

The real power plan is the one of the host. Whatever the VM thinks it's
doing has not much importance, since not only it's the host's scheduler
that handles CPU and I/O, but even its virtual CPUs are only processes
started by VMware that emulate a CPU.

So you might as well leave the power plan of the VM at High Performance.
This will not cause any problem for the host.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's what I was thinking too.
I'm trying to understand if there's any performance difference in leaving the Power Plan as Windows defaults or if the "High Performance mode" (for example) gives me any boost in performance.

Comment: It's better to let the host manage the CPU and I/O. If the OS in the VM interferes too much, the result can only be negative performance for the VM. There's no logic in the VM awarding time-slices to its processes, when the host does the same and the length and number of them might not be the same in host and guest. This might lead to the VM not using all the resources that the host is ready to give. So I recommend High Performance for the VM - it can't use more resources than the host is willing to give.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Host machine with an Operating System, VMware and then a Guest machine, then the Host Machine and Operating System power plan will take precedence and the Guest machine really does not have a power plan. The guest hardware, CPU and drivers are all virtual and supplied by the host.

I am using VMware Workstation Pro V17 on a Windows 11 Pro Host machine.  You can suspend the Guest Machine using the VMware App controls. That works fine.

This facilitates suspending machines in an orderly way so that you can shut down the VMware App and restart the host. The guest machines will can be easily un-suspended when VMware is back online.

If you have VMware ESX bare metal and each guest is separate and not much dependent on the host, then each guest may have its own power management plan.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was referring to a slightly different scenario: ESXi with a Windows Guest machine and editing the Power Plan of the Windows Guest machine.

It seems abusurd but I can't find evidences about the difference in performance between having a guest on Balanced or High Performance (or custom) Windows Power Plan on a Guest OS.